# How to show unanswered emails in Gmail where I asked a question?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I’m looking for a script or tool I can use to show threads in Gmail where I sent the last message AND asked a question.

I was able to get threads in Gmail where I sent the last message using [this script](https://web.archive.org/web/20131231004200/http://jonathan-kim.com:80/2013/gmail-no-response/) but that includes a lot of emails where my response closed out the thread.

I want to filter further to only show emails where my last message contained a “?” character - and just as importantly, the “?” character needs to have showed up in the new part of my last message and not in one of the other message appended further down the message.

Here is what I tried:

```
 // Filter threads where I was the last respondent.
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i],
        messages = thread.getMessages(),
        lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1],
        lastFrom = lastMessage.getFrom(),
        lastTo = lastMessage.getTo(),  // I don't want to hear about it when I am sender and receiver
        lastMessageIsOld = lastMessage.getDate().getTime() < minDaysAgo.getTime();

            var body = lastMessage.getRawContent();

    if (isMe(lastFrom)

        &&

       (body.indexOf("?") > -1)

        && !isMe(lastTo) && lastMessageIsOld && !threadHasLabel(thread, ignoreLabel)) {
      markUnresponded(thread);
      numUpdated++;
    }
  }
```

My addition to the linked script was the `(body.indexOf("?") > -1)` part, though now that I'm looking at it, I'm not sure that is working at all, and I assume that it would also find question marks further down in the last message, whereas the intention is to only find them in the new part of the last message.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's a bit too minimal for me.

Comment: The whole script is at the link. The only part I added is the the excerpt I shared. Still pretty new here, sorry if I didn’t do this right.

Comment: I not familiar with that link so I'm not going to follow it.  I'd prefer that you paste the code into the question like everybody else does.  That way if the link goes away the question will still be complete enough so that other users can benefit from the question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `?` is character used for other things than asking a question, i.e. it could be included in URLs. Considering this it's very likely that you should use something more complex than `String.prototype.indexOf()` like https://cloud.google.com/natural-language

Related

- [Newbie gmail plugin developer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61239582/1595451)